# Динамическое создание JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Есть JFrame, который создал через WindowBuilder в Eclipse. Добавил на него JLabel, и на сам JLabel повесил иконку. Вот как создался JLabel:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("");
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\main.png"));
label.setBounds(100, 123, 101, 75);
contentPane.add(label);
```

Так же на окне есть кнопка. При нажатии на кнопку должен создаться еще один объект JLabel:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("");
        label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\main.png"));
        label2.setBounds(170, 123, 101, 75);
        contentPane.add(label2);
    }
});

btnNewButton.setBounds(166, 32, 89, 23);
contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
```

Но когда я нажимаю на кнопку, ничего не создается
Где я ошибся?

Comment: Уточните а в случае если свернуть и развернуть окно вашей программы (конечно после нажатия на кнопку ) ничего не измениться?)

Comment: @PeterSlusar кнопка исчезает в таких случаях